# access floating windows in DigitalMicrograph

Tags: dm-script

I would like to arrange the standard floating windows (palettes) in the DigitalMicrograph working space by scripting. To place them conviniently I need first to access them. In the GMS versions 1.x I did it by ChooseMenuItem command. However the items in the "Window" menu are not accesible anymore in GMS 2.x such a way. Any ideas how to access floating windows from script?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can.

However, there is the in-built "floating window palette layout" functionality - what is the reason, you don't use that?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may not be able to move gadget panels (=floating palettes), but you can open/close them by name

`void OpenGadgetPanel( String name )`
`void CloseGadgetPanel( String name )`

and you can open/close all of them using:

`void CloseAllGadgetPanels()`
`void OpenAllGadgetPanels()`

Answer (score 0):

One solution might be to use code other than DMscript. The floating window layouts are saved as registry entries at HKCU\SOFTWARE\Gatan\DigitalMicrograph\ and are quite possibly easy enough to manipulate through some code that will let you modify the registry.

UPDATE 2016-03-11:
I have now tried manipulating these values (through regedit), and it turns out you cannot change things while DM is running. But it would be possible to create code that backups the current layout, loads your preferred one and finally starts DM. It is also possible to write DMscript that will trigger an external program upon closing DM, so that you can restore the previous layout.

If all you want to do is bring them from one installation to the next, just export them one by one. Then make sure to delete any of the same name before importing. This works well, but as always, be careful in the registry!